# Fetch values from checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I have seen various posts on `fetching values from checkboxes using jquery` so I decided to try it my own way but somehow this is not working. Please someone tell me what is the problem with the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[name='check[]'").click(function(){
  
  var a=$(this).is(":checked").val();
  $.each(a,function(index,value){
   $("#fruits").html(value);
   })
  
 })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="mango">Mango
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="apple">Apple
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="cherry">Cherry<br>
</form>
<div id="fruits"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the self explanatory code below, will clarify a lot of things...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='check[]'").click(function() {

    // Reset HTML
    $("#fruits").html("");
    
    // Iterate on all checked checkboxes
    $("input[name='check[]']:checked").each(function() {
      // Append to HTML
      $("#fruits").append(this.value);
    })

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="mango">Mango
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="apple">Apple
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="cherry">Cherry<br>
</form>
<div id="fruits"></div>
```

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe always keep your browser console open. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Sure, will do that from now on.

Comment: @Don'tDownvoteMe glad my answer helped. Do mark it correct :)

Comment: Sure! You have been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

There are syntax errors on your code.

If you want to show all the checked checkbox, you can:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[name='check[]'").click(function() {

    //This will get all the checked checkbox and get the values
    var f = $("input[name='check[]']:checked").map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join();

    //This will update the div
    $("#fruits").html(f);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="mango">Mango
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="apple">Apple
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="cherry">Cherry<br>
</form>
<div id="fruits"></div>
```